# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tag -- python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Trying to make a data miner, I have all the urls in an array but once I try to take on the scraper gives me this error:

```
$TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tag -- python
```

This is my full code for the scraper:

```
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def myScraper(sc):

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
quote_page = []

for row in csv_f:
    quote_page.append(url+row[0])


i=1
for var in quote_page:
    num_dat = []
    txt_dat = []
    num_dat2 = []
    txt_dat2 = []

    s.enter(5,1,myScraper, (sc,))
    sleep(5)

    print(quote_page[i])

    page = urlopen(quote_page[i])

    i = i+1

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    data_store = []
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):  # find table rows 
        tds = tr.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'fieldData'}) # find all table cells 
        for i in tds: # returns all cells from html rows
            if i != []: # pops out empty cells from returned data 
                data_store.append(i.text)
                #print(i.text)
                #print("\n")
    data_store2 = []
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'): 
        tds2 = tr.find_all('td', attrs={'class': 'improvementsFieldData'})
        for i in tds2: 
            if i != []: 
                data_store2.append(i.text)

    for j in data_store: 
        if ',' in j and ' ' not in j:
            lft_dec = j[:j.index(',')].replace('$', '')
            rght_dec = j[j.index(','):].replace(',', '')    # drop the decimal
            num_dat.append(float(lft_dec+rght_dec)) # convert to numerical data
        else:
            txt_dat.append(j)

    for j in data_store2: 
        if ',' in j and ' ' not in j:
            lft_dec = j[:j.index(',')].replace('$', '')
            rght_dec = j[j.index(','):].replace(',', '').replace('Sq. Ft', '')    # drop the decimal and Sq
            num_dat2.append(float(lft_dec+rght_dec)) # convert to numerical data
        elif ('Sq. Ft' and ',') in j: 
            sqft_dat_befcm = j[:j.index(',')].replace(',', '')
            sqft_dat_afcm = j[j.index(','):].replace(' ', '').replace('Sq.Ft', '').replace(',', '')
            num_dat2.append(float(sqft_dat_befcm+sqft_dat_afcm))
        else:
            txt_dat2.append(j)
    print(num_dat)
    print(txt_dat)
    print(num_dat2)
    print(txt_dat2)







 s.enter(5, 1, myScraper, (s,))
 s.run()
 f.close
```

Basically my goal for this program is given an array of url's can I open a browser scrape off the first one then wait for an interval amount of time and repeat until the array is done.

EDIT*** Sorry first time posting on this. Here is the full stackTrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\Desktop\HouseProject\AhmadsScraper.py", line 85, in 
<module>
    s.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\Anaconda2\lib\sched.py", line 117, in run
    action(*argument)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmad\Desktop\HouseProject\AhmadsScraper.py", line 32, in 
myScraper
    print(quote_page[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tag
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full traceback? So one can understand what line throws the error?

Comment: Yeah definitely! Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are using the same variable `i` as a counter and as an inner loop variable. How about using `enumerate` instead?

```
for idx, var in enumerate(quote_page):
    ...
    print(quote_page[idx])

    page = urlopen(quote_page[idx])
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much! haha Can't believe I missed that it makes sense now! I just fixed it and it worked!! thanks again!